# How do i adjust the duration of a user event in PyGame?

Tags: python, variables, events, pygame

A feature of one of the games I'm working on includes an obstacle event timer, where I gradually increase the difficulty of the game over time by gradually adjusting the duration of the timer.

I've tried creating a variable that is responsible for holding it and adjusting that, but after trying this I have noticed that the duration of it doesn't work.

```
missle_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
missle_timer = 4500
pygame.time.set_timer(missle_event, missle_timer)


for events in pygame.event.get():
    if game_active:
        if events.type == missle_event:
            missle_timer -= 100
```

dosen't work

Comment: do you need to call `pygame.time.set_timer()` after you decrease the `missle_timer`? It doesn't look like it is getting updated after you update your `missle_timer` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) again after changing the time inteval:

```py
missle_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
missle_timer = 4500
pygame.time.set_timer(missle_event, missle_timer)

while True:
    for events in pygame.event.get():
        if game_active and events.type == missle_event:
            missle_timer -= 100
            pygame.time.set_timer(missle_event, missle_timer)

    # [...]
```

If you call `set_timer` again for an event ID, no new timer will be created, only the time interval of the existing timer will be changed. Calling `set_timer` with argument 0, stops the timer.